# Flutter: Building and distributing a .ipa File without Mac/Apple Developer Account?

Tags: ios, macos, dart, flutter, travis-ci

I'm new to Flutter and Travis CI, so im having minor problems setting up the following. From what i read, it should be possible, but im not sure how exactly.

My current setup uses my existing Travis CI account, to build all my changes using `flutter build ios --no-codesign`. This generally works and should output a `Runner.app`-File.
My aim now is, to transform this File into a usable .ipa, which i can distriute to my personal iPhone/iPad via www.diawi.com.

I know that it is generally possible, to make Travis CI to commit results back to github, and i also know, that it should be possible, to build/create an .ipa from the .app file using the CLI of XCode.

Can someone help/hint me with building a full `build.sh`, which performs the flutter build, the xcode build, the ipa-extraction and the push of the .ipa to git?